# Need to close Jquery UI dialog from controller action in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am building a site where I am calling a partial view within a jquery ui dialog box.  Within the partial view there is a 'save' button that commits the data on the form to the database.  Currently it redirects to a different view.  I would like it to instead close the dialog box.  I am unable to get it to properly call the function to close the dialog box.

Here is my code:

In the View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".diagSave").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("<div></div>")
                    .dialog({
                        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                        modal: true,
                        width: 1000,
                        success: function () {
                        $('#diagSave').dialog('close');
                    }
                    })

                    .load(this.href);
                })

            });
</script>
```

In the Controller:

```
return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Can someone please help point out how I can accomplish this?

Comment: can the save routine be moved into the main form so the save button can be added in the options of the original dialog definition?

Comment: Where did you added this script ? On main view or partial View ?

Comment: @perdido, this is on my main view.

Comment: @steve, I would prefer to leave everything where it is at unless closing the dialog from the controller is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to handle the save click in jquery, use .serialize to send the form collection to your controller, then close the dialog.

```
var formvalues = $('#yourformparentdiv form').serialize();
$.ajax({
     url: siteRoot + 'Home/YourControllerMethod',
     data: formvalues,
     async: true,
     type: "POST",
     ...
```

Comment: I would prefer to leave everything working as it is unless closing the dialog from the controller is not possible

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle the close and save from the partialview you need to handle the close within a click event there.

```
$("#partialview_savebutton").click(function(e){
    var $dlg = $(this).parents(".ui-dialog");
    //save the data
    $dlg.dialog("close");
});
```

You need to ensure that this method is bound when you load the content into your dialog.

I generally include this at the end of my dialog open routine.

```
if(typeof initDlg == 'function') initDlg();
```

And then bind my event handlers and configure any validation I need within a defined `initDlg(){}` defined in my partialview.

Comment: What is needed in the controller to trigger the execution of the close function?

Comment: nothing in the controller, but the first code in my answer in the partial view.  You need to find the dialog element, and then call `close`

Comment: Some relevant html / js that gets loaded into your dialog would be helpful.